# from testsrv.srv import * [ImportError: No module named testsrv.srv]

Tags: ros, module, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I'm trying to make a ROS service, but I'm getting "ImportError: No module named testsrv.srv".

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding : utf-8 -*-

from testsrv.srv import *
```

I've uncommented into the CMakeLists.txt:

```
#uncomment if you have defined messages
rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
rosbuild_gensrv()
```

And part of my directory tree is this:
http://pastebin.com/882TacQ2

What is the problem? Why can't I import the srv file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66338/from-testsrv.srv-import-*-%5Bimporterror:-no-module-named-testsrv.srv%5D/) by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since it seems like you are using `rosbuild` and not `catkin` to build your packages, if you check out the `rosbuild` version of [rospy Publisher and Subscriber tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber), you'll notice that the Python scripts start with two lines that look like

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('beginner_tutorials')
import rospy
```

It looks to me like your test script is just missing these lines.  If your `manifest.xml` is correct, you should just need to convert *'beginner_tutorials'* to your package name.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1